# Cookie.Path doesn't work with Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-9

I'm creating cookie during login. The cookie scope is suppose to be limited to path.

```
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiryMinutes);
    cookie["username"] = username;
    SetCookieValue(cookie, "username", username);
    SetCookieValue(cookie, "password", password);
    SetCookieValue(cookie, "domain", domain);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Secure = true;
    cookie.Path = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

The problem is that while this code works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't work in Internet Explorer (and Opera). The problematic line is the last one - when setting cookie.Path parameter here, IE discards (I think) the cookie. I've debugged this with Chrome console, and the cookie is created succesfully with the correct path (say, /application ).

What can possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cookie.Path = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

to this

```
cookie.Path = "/";
```

I am assuming you want to apply the cookie to the whole domain.

Comment: Nope, I need the cookie to be path specific. It works when setting to "/", no worries. The trouble starts when setting it to something different than /.

Comment: Can you post your HTTP Response header.